# how to unregister an OSGi service

Tags: java, eclipse, service, osgi

I have the following test code, which should register and than unregister a test service. I tested it in an Eclipse 4.5.2 Mail-Demo appliation. The problem is that the service is not unregisted, the second call for the service is not null.

```
BundleContext bundleContext = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getBundleContext();

ServiceRegistration<ITestService> registration = bundleContext.registerService(ITestService.class, new TestService(), null);

ServiceReference<ITestService> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ITestService.class);
bundleContext.ungetService(serviceReference);

serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ITestService.class);
System.out.println("should be null but is not: " + serviceReference);
```

This is the output I get:

```
should be null but is not: {unregister.osgiservice.ITestService}={service.id=172, service.bundleid=8, service.scope=singleton}
```

How do I unregister the service correctly?

EDIT:
 
Ok I found `ServiceRegistration.unregister()`, if I add the code below the service is unregisted. Which brings up the next question, how do I get the `ServiceRegistration` from another place where the service is registered?

```
registration.unregister();

serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ITestService.class);
System.out.println("now the service is null: " + serviceReference);
```

Output:

```
should be null but is not: {unregister.osgiservice.ITestService}= service.id=174, service.bundleid=8, service.scope=singleton}
now the service is null: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the answer of greg above, I found this nasty workaround using internal classes:

```
((org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceReferenceImpl) serviceReference).getRegistration().unregister();
```

Sure this is bad, but I need a solution to get the `ServiceRegistration`. I can't store the `ServiceRegistration` on startup since I'm using [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/) (former Spring DM) to register my services.

Comment: This is indeed very bad. Anything with 'internal' in the package is not part of the Eclipse API and may be changed at any time.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, didn't find a better way. For my usecase this does the job.

Comment: VERY bad practice that us sure to fail one day and prohibits the use of oher frameworks.

Comment: As stated in the answer, it is nasty and I know it is very bad. Internal classes should not be used and a cast to an implementation class is always very bad practice.
Still, since I'm in control of the target platform / framework, this solution is ok for me.
If this breaks during an update, I will need to take another look at it. Same if the OSGi framework changes.
I would be very happy to change this code if somebody has a better solution, but until then this solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`ungetService` just drops the particular service reference, it does not unregister the service.

`registerService` returns a `ServiceRegistration` which you can use to unregister the service:

```java
ServiceRegistration<ITestService> reg = bundleContext.registerService(ITestService.class, new TestService(), null);

...

reg.unregister();
```

It is up to you to track the service registrations. Many plugins store them in the plugin Activator. It is also common to register the service in the Activator `start` method and unregister in the `stop` method.

Comment: "getServiceReference returns a ServiceRegistration" did you mean "returns a ServiceReference"?

Comment: Sorry I meant registerService

Comment: No, you need the registration.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question ("how do I get the ServiceRegistration from another place where the service is registered?")... the answer is that you can't. Only the person who registered the service is supposed to unregister it.

Comment: The party that receives the ServiceRegistration is responsible for the life cycle of the service. It is VERY bad practice to  unregister someone else's service. It is a rabbit hole that quickly sinks you if you go down it. If you REALLY need to hide a service then implement a Service Hook.