# Unregister a service in wcm.io's AEM Mocks

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am following the guide presented by wcm.io on the proper usage of [AEM Mocks](https://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/usage.html). Specifically, I am interested in unregistering a service. The documentation provides useful code for registering a service but nothing for unregistering. I have already looked at this similar question by [flavio.donze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181447/how-to-unregister-an-osgi-service) but the solutions given to his question don't work in the case of AEM Context.

First, if I attempt to register a service as such:

```
ServiceReference ref = aemcontext.bundleContext().getServiceReference(MyServiceClass.class.getName());
```

It is registered in `bundleContext` but not in `aemcontext`. The `ref` object is indeed set, but `aemcontext` never truly holds the service and if I attempt to register a servlet that uses this service as such:

```
context.registerInjectActivateService(new MyServlet(), myParams);
```

This call fails because `MyServlet` references `MyServiceClass`. What does work is registering a service directly on `aemcontext`, as such:

```
aemcontext.registerService(MyServiceClass.class, new MyServiceClass());
```

However, when I then attempt to unregister this service as in the solutions provided to [flavio.donze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181447/how-to-unregister-an-osgi-service)'s question, neither solution works. I don't get an error and I suppose that something does happen to the `ServiceRegistration<MyServiceClass> reg`, but the service is never unregistered from the `aemcontext`. If I attempt to register it again afterwards with the second command above, I get an error indicating that:

```
Multiple matches found for unary reference 'myServiceClass' for class...
```

Can anyone please help me? Is there a quick way to unregister a service through AEM Mocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment I updated the answer:

1. Then just do 2 test methods. The context object is re-initialized before each test method
2. The right order to register services is important. Use `registerService` to register all Mock-services (e.g. created with Mockito). Then use `registerInjectActivateService` for all services that should be part of the JUnit-test. Because for `registerInjectActivateService` all referenced services must have been registered before.
3. You don't need to mock the SlingSettingsService. This service is already part of Sling Mocks - and changing the run-mode is supported too.

Here is an example OSGi service:

```
@Component(service = FakeService.class)
public class FakeService {

    @Reference
    private SlingSettingsService slingSettingsService;

    public boolean isAuthor() {
        return slingSettingsService.getRunModes().contains("author");
    }

    public boolean isPublish() {
        return slingSettingsService.getRunModes().contains("publish");
    }
}
```

Here is an JUnit test for this service:

```
public class FakeTest {

    @Rule
    public final AemContext aemcontext = new AemContext();

    private FakeService fakeService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        fakeService = aemcontext.registerInjectActivateService(new FakeService());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnAuthor() {
        aemcontext.runMode("author");
        assertTrue(fakeService.isAuthor());
        assertFalse(fakeService.isPublish());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnPublish() {
        aemcontext.runMode("publish");
        assertFalse(fakeService.isAuthor());
        assertTrue(fakeService.isPublish());
    }
}
```

---

***Old Answer***

1. You should **not unregister** a service in OSGi-Mocks (Sling-Mocks, AEM-Mocks). Why do you need this anyway? A Unit Test should test your functional code - but not that OSGi wiring is working. Just accept that you cannot verify everything in Unit test, even simple things like a non-starting bundle. Therefore you have health checks.
2. If you really, really need this! You can extend the test framework. It is **open source**. And maybe others could use it too.
3. Alternatively take a look into **Pax Exam** based Unit tests. In my opinion it is a little bit oversized for "normal" AEM projects. But it provides a real OSGi container. The big advantage is, that is can still run as a normal part of your maven build. In AEM projects I have seen such tests often introduced by technically interested guys. But in reality these tests only proved that you can have a real OSGi container in your Unit tests. Normal developers will not touch such tests, as it feels too complicated for them.
4. Finally take a look in **Server-side JUnit tests**. The problem is, that you need an AEM instance and managed test data during your build. Also metrics like code coverage are difficult to measure. But I would recommend this anyway, if you have tests that heavily depend on AEM features. Tests with 50 lines of mocking a LiveRelationshipManager are often worthless. Then better run them server-side with a real AEM. Also the **AEM project archetype** already providing integration tests (= server-side JUnit tests). But even there you have to start/stop services, for testing WHAT?

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html

https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I need to unregister a service because of a very peculiar situation I'm in: I have business logic that executes when the user is on Author, namely when SlingSettingsService has "author" as a run mode, and when it doesn't. And so to test this, I thought:

Test 1: Register SlingSettingsService with "author" as such:

aemcontext.registerService(SlingSettingsService.class, new MockSlingSettingService(newRunModes));

Test 1: Register it without "author" in newRunModes. But I need to unregister the service before re-registering with different params.

Comment: Ok, I'm adding a new answer.

Comment: Hello! Thanks again for answering! Point 1 was very useful and the code works! As for Point 2, I have another service which has a mandatory reference to SlingSettingsService. If I don't mock it and explicitly pass it to aemcontext, I get this error:

org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.ReferenceViolationException: Unable to inject mandatory reference 'slingSettingsService' for class MyService : no matching services were found.

And so I am forced to mock SlingSettingsService and register it manually as in my previous answer.

Comment: This seems wrong. It should be injected automatically. I will update my answer with an explicit service.

Comment: In General use `registerService` you register all Mock-services (e.g. created with Mockito). Then use `registerInjectActivateService` for all services that should be part of the JUnit-test. But as you found out, for registerInjectActivateService all referenced services must have been registered before.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I have to explicitly mock and pass SlingSettingsService to aemcontext. aemcontext doesn't know what it is unless I do so.